# Open Graph Meta Tag Overwritting Yoast, WordPress

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I'm trying to change the `og:url` content on specific posts but I am unsure how to implement my changes from the functions.php file.

I have tried doing this using the content I have found on the internet but believe it has been updated since then.

I have updated the `class-opengraph.php` file in the the wordress-seo plugin folder which works, please find my edits below:

```
public function url() {
  $url = apply_filters('wpseo_opengraph_url',
                        WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()->canonical(false));

  if (is_string($url) && $url !== '' ) {
    if (is_page(32721)) {
      $this->og_tag('og:url', esc_url('testing'));
    } else {
      $this->og_tag( 'og:url', esc_url( $url ) );
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to modify the plugin files directly because when you update the plugin, you will lose all your changes to those files.

There are two solutions that I have found to do such thing.

1. You get the instance of the class `WPSEO_Frontend`, then update it's options for the `og:url`.

e.g.

```
$object = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
$object->options['og_url'] = esc_url( $url );
```

This can be added before the `wp_head()`

2. You can use [`add_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) to hook a function to the filter action. We use the filter action below.

> Filter: 'wpseo_opengraph_url' - Allow changing the OpenGraph URL

e.g.

```
function update_og_url($url) {
  return "http://www.yoursampleurl.com";
}
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_url', 'update_og_url', 10, 1);
```

Source: [Wordpress SEO API](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/)